# Преобразование строки из символов '\u0434\u0438...' непосредственно в unicode в Питоне 2

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7

Вот код:

```
# coding: utf-8

string = '\u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430, \u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0445\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f'
print string
```

В консоль получаем

```
D:\Python27\python.exe /test.py
\u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430, \u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0445\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f
```

Если сделать так

```
# coding: utf-8

string = u'\u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430, \u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430 \u0434\u043b\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0445\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f'
print string
```

то в консоль получим правильный вывод

```
диета, диета для похудения
```

Но дело в том, что я получаю переменную string извне, и никак не могу преобразовать ее как во втором варианте.

То есть в итоге мне нужен код такого типа:

```
# coding: utf-8

string = string # здесь манипуляции по преобразованию строки из символов юникода в нормлаьный вид
print string
```

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, `type(string)`

Comment: D:\Python27\python.exe /test.py
<type 'str'>

Comment: У меня питон 33 делает `print('\u0434\u0438')` нормальным русским текстом в: IDLE Windows, Windows Console, IDLE Ubuntu, Ubuntu Console.

Comment: Если я правильно понял — у автора в строке (полученной из внешнего источника) находится, по сути, результат `repr(unicode_text)`. Парсер языка, в этом случае, не при чем.

Comment: если вход это json text, то следует json парсер использовать вместо `unicode-escape`: `json.loads(r'"\u0434\u0438\u0435"')`

Answer (score 6):

Если я все правильно понял, то самое простое — вот так:

```
>>> print unicode(r'\u0434\u0438\u0435\u0442\u0430', 'unicode-escape')
диета
```

(В примере «r» просто для ясности, что ничего не декодируется «само», парсером языка.)

Comment: Спасибо, это работает print unicode(string, 'unicode-escape')!